# Move all ls output and symlink

Tags: bash, shell

I want to move some of my files in directory to another drive and create symlink for each of them in the old directory that will point to the new directory.

For example,

```
[root@localhost olddir]# ls *.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 51940340 Mar 31  2014 zx2014033121.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 38341784 Apr  1  2014 zx2014033122.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 21838676 Apr  1  2014 zx2014033123.MYD
```

Now I want to move all of them to /mnt/backup and create a symlink for each of them like:

```
[root@localhost olddir]# ls *.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 51940340 Mar 31  2014 zx2014033121.MYD -> /mnt/backup/zx2014033121.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 38341784 Apr  1  2014 zx2014033122.MYD -> /mnt/backup/zx2014033122.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 21838676 Apr  1  2014 zx2014033123.MYD -> /mnt/backup/zx2014033123.MYD
```

I have too many files to move so doing it manually will take a lot of time. Whats is the easiest way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in *; do mv $i /mnt/backup; ln -s /mnt/backup/$i $i; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define the glob:

for i in `ls *`; do mv $i /mnt/backup; ln -s /mnt/backup/$i $i; done

Or if it is a *lot* of files, ls might choke, in which case this:

find ./* -type f -exec mv {} /mnt/backup/ \; -exec ln -s /mnt/backup/{} {} \;